# Do ensemble techniques increase VC-dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, vc-dimension

Techniques like Adaboost use a ensemble of weak classifiers to obtain a "better" classifier.

Does(Can) the final classifier have a greater VC-dimension than the weak classifier?

An intuitive explanation  would suffice.

Comment: Well, just thinking about the definition of VC-dimension, do you think (say) boosted decision stumps can shatter a larger number of points than a single decision stump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the ensemble method you use. Usually the VC-dimension increases. But in the case of AdaBoost, you can find the answer here: 
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr08/cos511/scribe_notes/0305.pdf
http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~yfreund/papers/IntroToBoosting.pdf